# Prove that $(()())\in P$ (the set of balanced paranthesis) and $))(() \notin P$

Tags: induction, computer-science, context-free-grammar

Given the recursive definition of $P$ (the set of balanced paranthesis):

Base: $() \in P $.
Recursive step:
 if $w \in P$ then: 
  $$(w) \in P$$ $$()w \in P$$ $$w() \in P$$

And I have to prove that $(()()) \in P$ and $))(() \notin P$. 
For the first one, can I assume that the starting word is $()() \in P$, then by applying the first rule I get $(()())$. And for that starting word $()() \in P$. I can asume that the starting word is $() \in P$, then by appling the third rule I get $()() \in P$.

However this reasoning doesn't seem correct. And I don't how to extend this possibly incorrect reasoning to the second part.

What is the right way to do it. At least, how should I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$() \rightarrow_2 ()() \rightarrow_1 (()()).$

For the second part, it is clear (can be proved by induction) that, for every element of $P$, there always is a $($ on the further left.

Comment: Can you post a sketch of the proof by induction, for the second part?

Comment: Base case: $() \in P$

Answer (score 2):

Define the *imbalance* of a word $u$ on the alphabet $\{(,)\}$ as $|u|_( - |u|_)$, that is, the difference between the number of occurrences of $($ and $)$ in $u$.
There is a nice characterisation of the set of balanced parenthesis:

> A word on the alphabet $\{(,)\}$ is balanced if and only if its imbalance is $0$ and the imbalance of each of its prefixes is nonnegative.

It follows that $(()())$ is balanced and $))(()$ is not.